Automatic publication list in group webpage
I manage my research group website, and whenever a member of the group publishes something/posts it on the arXiv, I'm supposed to add it to the list (along with DOI, URL, status, etc.). But it's hard to keep track of them consistently, and sometimes we just forget to do it.
I was wondering if there is a way to automatically fetch publications from a given list of authors, so that when something is published, the website updates automatically.
Does anyone know such tool? Even some API that I can use for my website is fine.

You might not like the results. People share names. People's names are represented differently at different sites. Give the members a simple way to let you know of an update.

@Buffy: in the age of ORCID, that sounds like it should be a non-problem. (I do emphasize "should".) But seriously, that sounds like something ORCID should already offer. Alternatively, link to each member's ORCID page. Then, of course you are at the mercy of ORCID being up to date. And if you rely on Google Scholar, same issue. If you use both, you need to filter out duplicates. In any case, have people review any auto-generated list, and give them an easy way to correct erroneous entries.

@StephanKolassa I don't think ORCID automatically indexes arXiv preprints.

Frankly, interfacing with an API sounds a lot harder than ... just keeping track? Even if your group is massive, a pub a week is like 10 minutes worth of work.

I say this because names are natural-language objects, and the mess of journals and preprint servers doesn't lend itself to a clean solution. When I visit a group's webpage that's where the manually curated list should be.

Most university group webpages I've seen have a lovely manually curated list of publications that was last updated roughly 5 years ago when everyone in the department was forced to redo their webpage by administration fiat.

@JonCuster The natural cycle for university webpages is to flipflop between "This list is difficult to maintain, let's extract it automatically from XYZ" and "The data in this list is garbage, let's manually maintain it."

@xLeitix At least they're consistent in it being an unfunded mandate with no support.

@AzorAhai-him- programming a couple of lines of code is not an hard task, especially because we're a CS group. I prefer spending some time working on something that will automate such annoying task for the rest of my career, rather than doing it by myself. Then obviously such an API must exist, and that's the problem pointed out by others.

I disagree with some of the concerns raised in the comments. The Institute of Applied Analysis at Ulm University has been using such an automated approach for quite some years and it works very well in my experience: link to their page

@NYG I'm a competent programmer as well, and left my comment based on that evaluation.

ORCID is the way to go, because for US federal sponsors, it's being integrated into systems like SciENcv, which is required for NSF proposals and the link can be used in NIH biosketches.  It can also help fill out forms for you automatically.  ORCID accepts data uploads as well, so you can output from Google Scholar directly and upload into ORCID.

@JochenGlueck That is not what OP asks, but a simpler version: it includes only Arxiv, not all journal publications. It is significantly easier to do that when you have a single source that already disambiguates authors with the same name.

@FedericoPoloni: "That is not what OP asks: it includes only Arxiv" Well, it is a pragmatic solution that solves two issues mentioned by the OP: it avoids annoying manual work and it avoids forgetting to include new articles. Of course, it only works if it's common in OP's group to post all preprints to arXiv. It also includes the DOI of the journal publication in case that the authors include it in arXiv. (Admittedly though, many authors - including myself - are sloppy about this.) Sure, the solution is not perfect, but looking for perfect software solutions rarely leads to good outcome.

Here's an example from my former lab.

@JochenGlueck This seems nice. Actually many journals support automatic update of the DOI to the arXiv upon publication

Your first stop should probably be your university library. Librarians at a research university in 2024 are very well aware of publication databases, different ways of interfacing with them, and what issues you will face (names vs ORCIDs, what metadata is and isn't available, etc.). Based on the little experience I have, you are probably underestimating the challenge, and a chat with the right person in your library would help manage your expectations a bit. In the end, most likely you will come to the conclusion that it's easier to manually maintain your records than deal with name clashes, missing entries, wrong / inconsistent metadata in different databases, de-duplication, publishing delays, etc.
Most importantly, your library will also know what your university already has in place in that regard. My university library, for example, already automatically extracts metadata for all papers (co-)authored by our staff from a dozen or more different places - and I suspect yours will too ("How many papers have our staff published in 2023?" is a common rectorate-level question the library needs to be able to answer). This data will almost certainly not be perfect, but you need to ask the question if you can realistically do better than them.

Thanks. I expect this task to be solved by some AI in the near future, since as many pointed out, it is all about working with natural language

@NYG I'm unsure. It's an area where people tend to get very upset about problems with data quality - if your AI misjudges your top paper as a workshop contribution people tend to be very displeased, similarly if the AI makes up a paper you never wrote. Even if that only happens (say) 2% of the time, it's the kind of thing where one time is already too many.

I would do a half-way thing: tell the members of your group that whenever they publish, they need to enter their publication into a centralized location. This can be a simple text file, with the relevant fields like author, journal, title etc, or it could be in bibtex format, or a spreadsheet, or a DB, whatever works for you. But this will be maintained manually, and it will be the responsibility of the authors to add their work there.
Next, you write a little script that parses that file and brings in any new publications. This means you don't need to rely on nobody else in the world ever having the same name as a member of your group, and while it is still a semi-manual process, this really isn't much work for anyone. Especially compared to actually getting the paper out. So you could include the step of adding the publication to the repository file as part of your group's publication process.
With this approach, you get most of the benefit of a full automated one (very little busywork for anyone, each person only needs to deal with their own publications and only once) without the drawbacks of the fully automated (more time to develop, error prone if relying on author names etc). Best of both worlds?

This is a very good idea. It will work particularly well if the staff has a personal interest in keeping the db up to date (which in turn friends on the reason of the list existing in the first place)

I have cobbled together a simple javascript solution to this quite some time ago that was mentioned above in a comment by @JochenGlueck. In its current form it is holding up surprisingly well. It is used to generate the preprint list of the Institute of Applied Analysis.
Originally I had tried to directly use arXiv public author identifiers and the myarticles widget. Turns out it is hard to convince people to create author identifiers or to use ORCID and such.
In order to use the script you need to adapt the variables authors (for arXiv identifiers), extra_authors (just the names in the format [SURNAME]_[INITIAL] without any spaces or special characters) and probably api_query_url (for the correct arXiv categories). Then you can include it into a website something like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
  extra_authors = new Array('Sauter_M');
</script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/share/script/arxprep2.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<div id="arxivfeed">
<p>Please wait while a list with our current arXiv preprints is generated...</p>
<p>This webpage requires JavaScript.</p>
</div>

I suggest to not bother with author identifiers as long as the names of the authors work. Maintenance consists in keeping the list of names up to date. You might need to copy all the required javascript files to the same server to avoid troubles with the same-origin policy.

Do you then pull the journal-ref/published DOI from the arXiv page to update the webpage when papers are published? Then it seems one has to rely on group members updating those fields, which, while good practice, also seems hard to guarantee.

@Anyon Yes, it tries to pull the DOI from arXiv. So this only works if one of the authors bothers to update the information there. For mathematics one could detect (with reasonable precision) which preprints have appeared by cross-checking with zbMATH Open.

So if I understand correctly this script assumes that Surname_Initial identifies each author uniquely?

@FedericoPoloni One can also use [SURNAME]_[FIRSTNAME] if the initial is not sufficient. If this still doesn't work one can use proper arXiv author identifiers. Actually, I just made a minor update to the script since I noticed that my colleagues nowadays use more/other arXiv categories. Due to the additional categories there were two false hits in the list that I was able to get rid of by fully specifying two firstnames.

It's not an AI, at least, but I doubt one could trust it. It is open to both false positives and false negatives.

@Buffy If you need perfection, you can use the script locally, manually correct any errors and then upload a static file.

Some universities use research information management system software like Pure to keep track of their student and faculty contributions. These do scrape data from repositories like Arxiv, but usually require manual approval from the researcher (to prevent false attribution because someone has the same name or initials). This has the advantage of the researcher only having to update one database rather than several. Pure has an API that you could use to update your webpage, speak to IT about it if that's what your university uses.
